# Ornstein-Ulhenbeck and convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, limits, stochastic-processes

Let this O-U equation :
$$
dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + \sigma dB_t,\ \ \ X_0=x
$$
where $x,\alpha<0,\sigma$ **are constants**.

I proved that $X_t\xrightarrow{d} X\overset{d}{=}\mathcal N (0, \frac{\sigma^2}{-2\alpha})$.

Is it possible to prove that with probability 1 the limit $\underset{t\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} X_t=X$ exists (a.k.a. convergence a.s) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, recall that the distribution of $X_t$ converges, but the process is ergodic - the measure defined by $X$ can be interpreted as the proportion of time spent by $X_t$ in a set as $t$ gets large.  In particular, $\lim_t X_t$ does not exist.

Comment: Even if $x,\ \sigma$ and $\alpha<0$ are constants ?

Comment: Yep. The OU process is like a Brownian particle in a potential.  Its sample paths explore the space - even leaving any compact set.  But the amount of time they spend in a region converges to the gaussian measure of that region over time.